# search in data returned by computed property vue

Tags: vue.js

I have computed property which returns the data from getters (vuex) which is again being used in template to show data.

```
computed: {
    returnlist() {
    
      return this.$store.getters[LIST]
    },
}
```

Now I have filters which has needs to do search within available result from computed property.

I am trying

```
method :{
  search() {
    this.returnlist.filter(el=>el.name==="test")

}
```

However this does not filter and if I console I am getting same array provided it matches with given name property.

Comment: `el.name="test"` Is this what you need exactly. I think you should be doing `el.name=="test"` instead.

Comment: it was typo, I have already === there, but no luck, my question is that can we search in data return by computed property

Answer (score 1):

Your `search` method is not returning anything. Depending on how you want to use it, you could either have your search function return the filtered array:

```js
methods: {
  search() {
    return this.returnlist.filter(el => el.name === "TEST");
  }
}
```

or you could have an object holding filter values in your component's `data` and change the filter values to adjust the returned filtered array:

```js
data: {
  filters: {
    name: 'Jack',
    minAge: 32
    maxAge: 40,
  },
},

computed: {

  filteredArray() {
    return this.$store.getters[LIST].filter(el => {
      return el.name === this.filters.name &&
            (el.age >= this.filters.minAge &&
             el.age <= this.filters.maxAge);
    });
  }
},
```

Comment: I can not directly search in computed property by default, it has to be done on button click only when user use filter, and I am not able able to filter within computed property

Comment: I don't understand @vuejsdev, what prevents you from doing something like: `@click="filter = "TEST"` on the filter button? Just replace the `"TEST"` with the value of a search field for example and you're good to go. Am I missing something?

Comment: I appriciate your response but I might have multiple response which I need to carry on so  I need to have multiple filters

Comment: Well it's not that hard @vuejsdev, just apply different conditions in the `filteredArray` computed. I updated the response to reflect what I mean.

Comment: thanks, really appriciate your help, but I dont have default value. and they can select either one value do filter, it is not mandatory to have all the filters to be selected, if selected more then two filter then AND otherwise OR

Comment: I like your answer but that is not solution for me, because I want to search in computed property as stated in my original post, but I am not getting desired result.

Comment: Well I guess I can't help you much more. Maybe update the question with a more detailed example of what you want, it may help.

Comment: when I do this return this.returnlist.filter(el => el.name === "TEST"); searching in computed property it does not do anything.